# Replace <br style="..."> with <br>

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I'm looking for a way or a regular expression to change a break tag like:

```
<br style="font-size:12.8000001907349px">
```

to:

```
<br>
```

Right now I'm using this, but doesn't work as expected.

```
preg_replace("/<br\W*?\/>/", "<br>", $the_string);
```

How can I change my code to get it to work?

Comment: `$the_string = preg_replace("~<br[^>]+/?>~", "<br>", $the_string);`

Comment: Tried every suggestion so far doesn't seem to have effect

https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Comment: @CSKoh Then what is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($the_string);` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried this on the actual code and got the right result. Stand corrected =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep it simple, like this:

```
preg_replace("/<br.*?>/", "<br>", $the_string);
```

Basically `.*?` means:

- **.*?** matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: ***?** Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<br>` tag into a `<br />` tag.

This will work:

```
preg_replace("/<br.*?\/>/", "<br />", $the_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this Regex expression for strings like:

```
Search this: <br anykindoftext>

preg_replace("/<br\s+.*>/", "<br>", $the_string);
```

When you search br tag with style you need:

```
Search this: <br style=“…”>
preg_replace("/<\s*br\s+style\s*=\s*".*"\s*>/", "<br>", $the_string);
```